# How to combine two dropdownlists change event JQuery function into one?

Tags: jquery

I want to combine these two function into one. `#Ctry,#Yd` are dropdown lists. Please show me the path. Thank you in advance.

```
$('#Ctry,#Yd').change(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("tal", "St")'
  $('#Rial').load(url, { ctry: $('#Ctry').val(),yd: $('#Yd').val() })
});

$('#Ctry,#Yd').change(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("tala", "St")'
  $('#con').load(url, { ctry: $('#Ctry').val(),yd: $('#Yd').val() })
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working? Can't you just use one `.change()` handler and just put the two `.load()` calls in it with their respective URLs?

Comment: @Phil, how to do that? Appreciated, if you could provide some sort of example. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil,Actually, I was trying this code `$('#Ctry,#Yd').change(function () {
  var url = '@Url.Action("tal", "St")'
  $('#Rial').load(url, { ctry: $('#Ctry').val(),yd: $('#Yd').val() })
 var url = '@Url.Action("tala", "St")'
  $('#con').load(url, { ctry: $('#Ctry').val(),yd: $('#Yd').val() })
});`

Comment: And did that code not work? If so, what went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just use one `.change()` handler and just put the two `.load()` calls in it with their respective URLs?

```
$('#Ctry, #Yd').change(function () {
  let data = {
    ctry: $('#Ctry').val(),
    yd: $('#Yd').val()
  }
  let rialUrl = '@Url.Action("tal", "St")'
  let conUrl = '@Url.Action("tala", "St")'
  $('#Rial').load(rialUrl, data)
  $('#con').load(conUrl, data)
})
```